# Livewire: create and update in two tables

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-9

First to say that I am a newbie in Laravel. I have started to develop the frontend of an APP in Laravel Nova with Livewire. The problem is that before, I was able to do operations in my controller but I don't know how to do it in the Livewire resource.

I have a simple form:

```
        <form wire:submit.prevent="submit" class="rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4">

        <input type="text" placeholder="Introduzca código" wire:model="code" class="md:inline-block ktext-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">
        <br>
        @error('code')
        {{$message}}
        @enderror
        <br>

        <input type="text" placeholder="Introduzca tipo" wire:model="access" class="md:inline-block ktext-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">
        <br>
        @error('access')
        {{$message}}
        @enderror
        <br><br>

        <x-jet-button type="submit">Crear Asistencia</x-jet-button>

    </form>
```

Which inserts three data into a table:

```
    public function submit()
{
    //validate
    $this->validate();
    Attendance::create([
        'code' => $this->code,
        'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        'access' => $this->access,
    ]);
```

But I want that in a second table, when the "code" field matches (it is in both tables and is a boolean) the code is update in this second table.

How would you do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not an app in production, it is part of my learning.

Comment: It'll be the same in a Laravel controller and a Livewire component. You can just run the update query with the where clause for that code, because if it doesn't exist, it won't update anything

Answer (score 0):

Im not a pro laravel but a think any like the code below can help with yout question:

```
    // If you have more than one register with same code:
    $infos = SecondTableModel::where('code', $this->code)->get();
    foreach ($infos as $info) {
        SecondTableModel::find($info->id)->update([
            'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            'access' => $this->access,
            // ... OTHERS FIELSDS 
        ]);
    }


    // If you have only one register on the second table with the same code
    SecondTableModel::where('code', $this->code)->first()->update([
        'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        'access' => $this->access,
        // ... OTHERS FIELSDS 
    ]);
```